# Lifetime of the async delegate invocation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, windows-services

I have the following code in my service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var cleaner = new Cleaner();
    Action action = cleaner.Run;
    action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```

I'm worried if I should move the delegate to an instance variable as the objects it uses might be collected by GC because they are only created locally.

Comment: Did you try to call [GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if an object that was still "in use" was collected? There is no sane answer to that question. For that reason the CLR guarantees that no object that is still being references will be garbage collected. You are safe, no matter how you write your code.

You don't even have the ability to get objects collected if they are still referenced. Even if you wanted to.

Comment: Can't `action` itself be collected?

Comment: It could, if no one was using it (for example after the call to BeginInvoke, maybe even during). Do you suspect that this causes problems? It can't/shouldn't.

Comment: So the `action` gets collected, then `cleaner` gets collected. So the thread that is still running `cleaner.Run` function will be left with invalid data.

Comment: What does "invalid" mean? See my answer. Such a thing does not exist.